# How does the diigolet bookmarklet get around cross-scripting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

http://www.diigo.com/tools/diigolet

Diigolet essentially allows you to use a bookmarklet to bookmark sites. With the bookmarklet I'm making, I also need to pass the current URL of the site the user is on to my server. Everytime I try this, I get a cross-scripting error.

Does anybody know how to bypass this like the diigolet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, they [work around the same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Navigation_and_content_inclusion_across_domains) by injecting a script tag with the different-domain URL rather than using an XMLHttpRequest. Note that this is different from a normal JSON request in that the JSON is wrapped in a callback function, for example:

```
myCallbackFunction(<JSON here>);
```

(This works because JSON is a subset of JavaScript's object literal notation.)

In their case, they hardcode the name of the callback function as `diigolet.callback`, but there exists a specification called [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) that JavaScript libraries [such as jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) support.

Under the JSONP specification, the name of the callback function is passed to the server via a `callback=myCallbackFunction` parameter in the GET request. Your server-side code needs to handle this appropriately to be able to handle JSONP requests from jQuery.

Comment: They're definitely using script injection.  This answer would be better if you show if/where JSONP, a more specific technique, is being used.

Comment: @Matthew: You're right - they hardcode the name of their callback function. Unfortunately, I cannot easily show the specific lines of the code because it is minified. I suppose you could get some picture of how it works by looking at Firebug's Net panel or Tamper Data.

Comment: To anyone whose curious, your server needs to return the callback in this format: If passed, "callback=callBackThisFunction" then the server needs to return "callBackThisFunction(JSON HERE)" In Django this would be: return HttpResponse(request.GET["callback"] + '(' + simplejson.dumps(jsonstring) + ')'). This is assuming you use the JSON.ajax() command and set dataType="JSONP". NOTE: request.GET['callback'] would equal "callBackThisFunction" in this example.